# Getting array in android is returning null

Tags: android, arrays, null

I have an array in an xml file that i'm trying to access, however it is returning null.

**XML:**

```
<array name="phone">
    <item>17809272426</item>
    <item>17809272426</item>
    //etc...
</array>
```

**Java:**

```
String[] phonenumber;
phonenumber = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.phone);
Toast callContact = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phonenumber[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
callContact.show(); //blank but it shouldn't be...
Intent contactdial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + (phonenumber[position])));
startActivity(contactdial);
```

Thanks =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just double check your [syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) there, instead of `array` use `string-array`.